# How to count in Hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, count, reduce

I have a huge list of titles. I want to count each title in the whole data set. For example:

```
`title`

A
b
A
c
c
c
```

Output:

```
title fre
    A   2
    b   1
    c   3
```

I am looking for a fast way using reduce function in Hadoop. I know the following way:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy('title').agg(f.count('*').alias('count')).show()
```

I also need to get titles with less than 10 occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use RDDs you can try this code:

```
grouped_rdd = (df.rdd.map(lambda r: (r[0], 1))
                 .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
                 .sortBy(lambda r: -r[1])    # descending order; remove - if ascending.
                 .take(10)
              )

grouped_df = spark.createDataFrame(grouped_rdd, ['title', 'count'])
```

But I'm not sure if this will be faster than `df.groupBy('title').count()`.

Comment: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 101.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 101.0 (TID 611, 192.168.1.102, executor driver): org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Device not configured`

Comment: @elham very strange error that should not be related to the code. Try restarting your application